# Regex Expression to extract coefficent of linear eq "2x-3y+0.5"

Tags: python, regex, linear-equation

I want to convert my eq to vector form so i need to extract the coefficient

`r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+"` I tried this but I am not able to get the "-" sign along with the integer.
For 2x-3y+0 i am getting `[2, 3, 0]` but I need `[2, -3, 0]`.

Comment: The `r"..."` looks like you are using Python. As already pointed out in the [tag:regex] tag guidance, this should be spelled out in your actual question.

Comment: Split the string on `[xy]\+?`.

Answer (score 1):

> The expression in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728275/6553328) is much better, since it does not capture the `+` for instance.

Being said that, my guess is your designed expression is also just fine, maybe we'd slightly modify that to:

```
[-+]?\d+\.\d+|[-+]?\d+
```

and it might likely work, since validation seems to be unnecessary.

#### [Please see the demo and explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/b97reO/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

matches = re.finditer(r"[-+]?\d+\.\d+|[-+]?\d+", "-0.2x-0.73y-0.11z-0.2x-0.73y-0.11")
linear_eq_coeff=[]

for match in matches:
    linear_eq_coeff.append(match.group())
print linear_eq_coeff
```

#### Output

```
['-0.2', '-0.73', '-0.11', '-0.2', '-0.73', '-0.11']
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /[-+]?\d+\.\d+|[-+]?\d+/gm;
const str = `-0.2x-0.73y-0.11z-0.2x-0.73y-0.11`;
let m;

arr = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
 if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
 }

 // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  arr.push(match);
 });
}

console.log(arr);
```

#### Advice

[wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) advice is that:

> Could simplify to `[-+]?(\d*\.)?\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a better regex.

```
>>>import re
>>>eqn = '2x-3y+0'
>>>re.findall(r'(-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))', eqn)
['2', '-3', '0']
```